# Particular column copy using autofilter

Tags: excel, vba

How can I copy particular column in excel VBA using auto filter?
I have data in a sheet from A to E Columns.
Criteria column is A and I would like copy only C and D columns to another sheet.

The following code copy all columns, but my need is two columns only  C & D

```
Dim ob as range
Set ob = Worksheets("ob").Range("a3:e27")

ob.Parent.AutoFilter.Range.Copy

With Sheet3.Range("a9")
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    .Select
End With
ob.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Intersect` to intersect your range with columns C and D

```
Dim FilteredColumnCD As Range
FilteredColumnCD = Intersect(ob.Parent.AutoFilter.Range, ob.Parent.Range("C:D"))

If FilteredColumnCD Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No filtered data"
    Exit Sub
End If

FilteredColumnCD.Copy

' rest of your code here …
```

Comment: @peh .. as per your suggestion i reset the code... but it throws error...plz...

Comment: `Set ob = Worksheets("ob").Range("a3:e27")  ob.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & Sheet3.Range("c2").Value fc = Intersect(ob.Parent.AutoFilter.Range, ob.Parent.Range("C3:D27")) fc.Copy With Sheet3.Range("a9") .PasteSpecial Paste:=8 .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats Application.CutCopyMode = False .Select End With`.